# SQL query to get group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have theses tables. I want to get the number of installations by agency that have at least one reading. How do I get this?

Thanks.

**repository**

| Column |
| --- |
| id |
| number |

**readings**

| Column |
| --- |
| id |
| repository_number |

**meter**

| Column |
| --- |
| id |
| installation_id |
| repository_id |

**installation**

| Column |
| --- |
| id |
| agency |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` as follows:

```
select i.agency, count(distinct m.id) meters
  from installation i 
  join meter m on m.installation_id = i.id
  join repository rp on rp.id = m.repository_id
  join reading r on r.repository_number = rp.number
 group by i.agency;
```